# Haskell: convert `type` to `data` statement

Tags: haskell, types, monads, algebraic-data-types, io-monad

What is an equivalent `data` statement for this Haskell `type` statement:

```
type CWIO a = CWorld -> (a, CWorld)
```

...that would allow me to write:

```
instance Monad CWIO where
    (action1 >>= action2) w0 =
        let (x1, w1) = action1 w0
            (x2, w2) = action2 x1 w1
        in  (x2, w2)
    return a = \world -> (a, world)
```

where CWorld:

```
data CWorld = CWorld {
    cin :: String,
    cout :: String
}
```

I'm working on a quest to "really grok" monads by actually building a "virtual IO monad" that actually works (in its "virtual universe"). Some kind of "understanding/explanation by building/engineering" for the concept of monads because **I'm the kind of person that needs to build something from scratch by myself in order to really understand that "something"**, so I'm going the same route here. The whole code context is here https://gist.github.com/NeuronQ/11119444/adbf0a9d6d17d4231d7ec68f565203f8dd75f702 , but it will probably seem meaningless and "atrocious" to any experienced Haskell programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like

```
newtype CWIO a = CWIO { unCWIO :: CWorld -> (a, CWorld) }
```

which will allow you to define the appropriate instances and to use `CWIO` and `unCWIO` to move back and forth between wrapped `CWIO` computations and the unwrapped underlying functions. `newtype` is a variant of `data` tailored and optimised for wrappers with a single constructor.

Note that by adopting such a definition for `CWIO` you will end up with something equivalent to the `State` monad specialised for a `CWorld` state.

Comment: ok, and what would the old types `String -> CWorld -> ((), CWorld)` or `String -> CWIO ()` (they were equivalent) become now? Like for the `cwWrite` function at line `23` in this: https://gist.github.com/NeuronQ/11119444 . The type error that I get after converting to `newtype` is `Couldn't match expected type 'CWorld -> ((), CWorld)' with actual type 'CWIO ()' The equation(s) for 'cwWrite' have two arguments, but its type 'String -> CWIO ()' has only one` and I can't figure out how to fix it now.

Comment: @NeuronQ Use the `CWIO` constructor to wrap the function: `cwWrite str = CWIO $ \(CWorld cin cout0) ->
((), CWorld cin (cout0 ++ "~ " ++ str ++ "\n"))`

Comment: Holy cow, I just made a Monad that represents IO-like-behavior in a "Console World" virtual universe and it works with `do` syntax and everything! (https://gist.github.com/NeuronQ/11119444) Thanks 1000x man! Now it's the first time when monads no longer seem as some mysterious things and I can really start to properly grok them...